# Overwrite Constructor to inject custom module helper

Tags: php, magento2.2.2

I have created a custom module. which rewrites \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success class by creating a custom module.

and i am able to make changes in prepareBlockData function but i want to inject helper class of my custom module in success block constructor below is the code i tried.

```
<?php

namespace Test\Buynow\Block\Magento\Checkout\Onepage;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{

    protected $_checkoutSession;


    protected $_orderConfig;


    protected $httpContext;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Test\Buynow\Helper\Buynow $buynowHelper, //custom module helper class which i want to inject
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->buynow = $buynowHelper; //custom module helper class which i want to inject
    }


    protected function prepareBlockData()
    {
        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $isReference= false;

        if($order->getReference()):
            $isReference = true;
        endif;

        $this->addData(
            [
                'is_order_visible' => $this->isVisible($order),
                'view_order_url' => $this->getUrl(
                    'sales/order/view/',
                    ['order_id' => $order->getEntityId()]
                ),
                'print_url' => $this->getUrl(
                    'sales/order/print',
                    ['order_id' => $order->getEntityId()]
                ),
                'can_print_order' => $this->isVisible($order),
                'can_view_order'  => $this->canViewOrder($order),
                'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'reference'=> $isReference
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

after doing this i have flushed cache and deployed static content but i am getting below error.

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\Session,

Comment: Remove generated class

Comment: Check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding correctly **Dependency Injection** in Magento2 can be tricky the first times. Take a look at this [Magento2 extend core block constructor](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222808/magento2-extend-core-block-constructor)

So, in your case you are extending **\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success**, which has following constructor (check it in your project better, maybe we use different versions & it may differ)

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    array $data = []
) {
    ...
```

But, in your class constructor you are calling...

```
parent::__construct($context, $data);
```

Which causes error, as it should be...

```
parent::__construct($context, $checkoutSession, $orderConfig, $httpContext, $data);
```

So, your constructor should look like this...

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    \Test\Buynow\Helper\Buynow $buynowHelper, //custom module helper class which i want to inject
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $checkoutSession, $orderConfig, $httpContext, $data);
    $this->buynow = $buynowHelper; //custom module helper class which i want to inject
}
```

Note that you don't really need to redeclare parent **protected** variables (        `$this->_checkoutSession`, `$this->_orderConfig`, etc...), as they will be declared when you call parent constructor, and your class will be able to access them. This would be required only with **private** variables